# Full-Text Search not showing results

Tags: sql-server

I have a sql table of products with one value of title 'Beko EV7100' when i search for 7100 this row is not in my search results when i search for EV7100 it is ok.
What am i doing wrong? you may see the query below.

```
SELECT *, ft.[Rank]
FROM [dbo].[STORE_PRODUCTS] AS sp with(nolock) 
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE([STORE_PRODUCTS], ( title,[short_description],[long_description],permalink_url,meta_keywords), 
ISABOUT ('*7100*', title WEIGHT(0.4), short_description WEIGHT(0.2),long_description WEIGHT(0.2), permalink_url WEIGHT(0.1), meta_keywords  WEIGHT(0.1)) ) AS ft
ON ft.[key] = sp.id     
and ft.[Rank] > 5
```

Answer (score 0):

try use % instead of *

```
SELECT *, ft.[Rank]
FROM [dbo].[STORE_PRODUCTS] AS sp with(nolock) 
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE([STORE_PRODUCTS], ( title,[short_description],[long_description],permalink_url,meta_keywords), 
ISABOUT ('%7100%', title WEIGHT(0.4), short_description WEIGHT(0.2),long_description WEIGHT(0.2), permalink_url WEIGHT(0.1), meta_keywords  WEIGHT(0.1)) ) AS ft
ON ft.[key] = sp.id     
and ft.[Rank] > 5
```